# How old is Samantha?

Tags: age, bewitched

In one episode of *Bewitched*, we see a painting of Samantha (we assume it's Samantha) which is set in old Salem by the looks of it.  This then raises the question of how old Samantha actually is, but the question is never truly addressed.  So, how old is Samantha at the time of the series (educated guesses are acceptable).

Comment: Both the questions you've asked are explitly answered in the Bewitched online magazine; www.harpiesbizarre.com. You may wish to give it a read...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a very extensive analysis of contextual clues from the episodes as to the various ages of the witches at [Bewitched @ Harpies Bizarre](http://www.harpiesbizarre.com/ageofwitches.htm):

> In # 3, Endora makes reference to having known Diogenes (400 BC).
>
> In # 5, Endora makes reference to having known Julius Caesar.
>
> In # 23, Endora says she cooked for the Roman Emperor, Claudius.
>
> In # 24, Endora makes reference to having known Helen of Troy (1180 BC).
>
> In # 160, Serena tells Phyllis that Endora admits to 1000.
>
> In # 168, Maurice says he and Endora knew Atilla the Hun (450 AD).
>
> In # 210, Endora says she has changed her mind many times in 3000 years.
>
> On the other hand:
>
> In # 171, Endora says she went to Shakespeare's plays as a little girl.
>
> In # 175, Endora refers to being a child bride when Samantha was born.
>
> In # 203, Endora again says she was a child bride. This time she defines it as being in 1670.
>
> In # 230, Endora says she was not born at the time of King Henry VIII (1570).

Ignoring the fact that several episodes specifically contradict each other, the general theme is that Endora is at least 3000 years old and that Samantha was (probably) born sometime between 1570 and 1600 which would make her approximately **390-400 years old** at the time of filming.

Comment: If you want a closer date, the biblical Witch of Endor who summoned a spirit for King Saul is supposed to be Endora - thus the name. So this would give some 2700ish years if she was young at the time.

Comment: @Oldcat - Again, context clues would suggest that witches are considered children for a hundred (or more) years.

Answer (score -2):

When Darrin went back in time to save Samantha from Henry VIII, Endorra said she had powers to get them there and back because during the time of Henry VIII, she had not yet been born.  So she was no older than 500-ish

Comment: This appears to relate to episode #230 (*How Not to Lose Your Head to Henry VIII: Part 2*), As I've noted in my answer above, this directly contradicts other statements that Endora has made in prior episodes.

Comment: @Valorum:  Since witches can obviously time travel, there's no reason Endora had to have been born 3000 years ago in order to have known someone from that far back. The only thing that directly contradicts 500 years old and your list of "age indicators" is the one statement about Endora changing her mind a lot of times over 3000 years.

Comment: @JRE - My take on it is that she's "very old" and that the writers were simply *inconsistent from one episode to the next* over the space of 250+ episodes, written at a time when computers were a rarity and being able to copy-check prior episodes meant getting them out of the studio library and re-reading them